# 200 Not registered error on sending group notification using GCM notification key

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send gcm group notifications to android devices from my rails server. But unfortunately I can't get it to work. But if I try to send the same message to single registration id, it works fine. So i checked it with curl-

```
curl -vvv -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header   
"project_id: MyProjectid" --header "Authorization: key=Mykey" --data @- 
"https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" << EOF
{
  "to": **"Reg_id"**,
  "data": {}
}
EOF
```

The above gives me `200 OK`. But here if I replace the `Reg_id` with the notification_key I get `200 NotRegistered` and the message was not delivered. So I did a little more research and found out when I send a gcm message the notification_key get unregistered by itself.

Below is the simple scenario with I made this assumption - If I create a new *notification_key* using curl it gives me the *notification_key*. If I create a new key using the same **notification_key_name** I get `notification_key already exists`. But once I send a notification using same notification_key, I get `200 Not registered error`. Then if I try to create a new *notification_key* using previous **notification_key_name** I get a new *notification_key*.

This seems very weird to me. Has anyone faced the same issue or found the solution for this?

Comment: I have notices the same exact behavior since Wednesday 7/10-15, with group notification_key's that worked fine the day before. Rotating API keys did not help. This makes me believe the error is on Google's side of things.

Comment: I'm getting `HTTP/1.1 200 NotRegistered` responses.

Comment: @VictorHäggqvist - If the issue is at Google's side of things, then GCM must be highty unreliable. This makes me wonder whether I should even use GCM.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this issue? This is happening in my case too. Also I am getting 200 NotRegistered in response header too while making a call via HTTPUrlConnection.  

Also, where to file this issue? is there any forum on googleGroups?

Comment: @satyenvishnoi device groups seems to be wonky some times, don't know why. Messaging to devices work fine though.

Comment: It started working now. I raised an issue in GCM github project and it seems they fixed it. @Heisenberg - Check now. It should work fine.

Comment: @satyenvishnoi : Yes. It started working now. I hope these kinds of unannounced issue won't occur in future.